# Rails 4 authenticity_token using multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

Regarding sessions in Rails using CookieStore, if I have two servers with the same Rails applications and configured the same way (identical for hashes, and config), I know that if one user hits the first server and starts a session, then if next requests hit the second server the application will work okay. That's ok for now.

But, regarding forms and authenticity_token, how do you deal with this (preventing CSRF)?

Suppose I have a Cookie hash session (using CookieStore) that is stored using the Cookies in client side (browser). So no session is used on the server side at all.

So, if I generate an authenticity_token from server 1 and then next request (POST from a form) hits server 2, the request will be rejected throwing an error or rails exception.

How do you deal with this? Sharing the authenticity_tokens in memory or using "middleware" software, for instance Redis key value storage so that every server can verify authenticity_tokens?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you actually tried it and received an error, or is it only an assumption? The CSRF token is based on the current session, and since the session information are stored in the cookie, it should work across several servers.

Answer (score 0):

As from Rails version 4 I see that:

"If you have secret_key_base set, your cookies will be encrypted. This goes a step further than signed cookies in that encrypted cookies cannot be altered or read by users. This is the default starting in Rails 4."

(Documentation of CookieStore, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html).

So I think the authenticity_token will be set in the session (Cookie-side) and then will be sent to the form as a hidden field, so next request will be validated independently of the server (server1, server2, and so on). So with encryption the authenticity_token will not be seen by users on client side. With no encryption it can be seen and can be a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

In UsersController You could use:

```
sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
```

from `Devise::Controllers::SignInOut`

In documentation for this We can read:

> Sign in a user that already was authenticated. This helper is useful for logging users in after sign up.
>
> All options given to sign_in is passed forward to the set_user method in warden.
>   The only exception is the :bypass option, which bypass warden callbacks and stores the user straight in session. This option is useful in cases the user is already signed in, but we want to refresh the credentials in session.
>
> Examples:

```
sign_in :user, @user                      
sign_in(scope, resource)
sign_in @user                             
sign_in(resource)
sign_in @user, event: :authentication  
sign_in(resource, options)
sign_in @user, store: false            
sign_in(resource, options)
sign_in @user, bypass: true            
sign_in(resource, options)
```